# Specify numeric column between 1 and 5

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to set up a numeric column in a postgresql table.
This column may only contain a number between 1 and 5.

How should i specify this in my postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-constraints.html)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    constraint_col integer  CHECK (constraint_col > 0 and constraint_col < 6)
);
```

Comment: You're kinder than me. For these sorts of "I left my DB101 homework too late" questions I tend to point at the docs and ask "so what did you already try?"

Comment: @CraigRinger I am like that in the mysql tag where lots of people take short cuts, but generally postgresql users seem well behave and I don't find myself casting close votes very often here (my usual habit on mysql tag)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [check constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use check constraint and specify the list or range.like

```
Create table poc_test (i_id   integer,
                  CHECK (i_id between 1 and 5));
```